# My enqueue script and css doesn't work in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I trying to create some admin pages for tutorial for WordPress. I have added standard `css` and `js` files with function that is `wp_enqueue_style`. It worked, but in `enqueue.php` file, commands doesn't work.

My codes in `enqueue.php`:

```
<?php
function theme_load_admin_scripts($hook){
if('toplevel_page_theme_option' != $hook){
    return;
}

wp_register_style('theme_admin', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/theme.admin.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all');
wp_enqueue_style('theme_admin');

wp_enqueue_media();

wp_register_script('theme-admin-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/js/theme.admin.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);
wp_enqueue_script('theme-admin-script');
}

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_load_admin_scripts');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use admin_init

```
add_action('admin_init', 'theme_load_admin_scripts');
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_init

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have fixed it.